# how do you say "write onto a piece of paper" in a more creative way?

Tags: phrases

I want to use an alternative to the expression

> write onto a piece of paper

I would like to rephrase this to sound more interesting. Can anyone provide suggestions?

Comment: I think this is a cool question, but could be improved by giving a more elaborate example of how you want to use it. Eg. give us some context.

Comment: Include everything in the body of the question. Mentioning in the title is not sufficient.

Comment: what about "scribble down"

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it depends on what you mean by "creative", or more specifically, what tone or color you want to set.

You could use some of the many idioms for this, for example "ink the deal", "get it in writing" or just simply "write it down." You might go for a deliberate misuse of an idiom, such as "carve it in ink", or "not-so-verbal contract". Our you might go nuts and abuse English's amazing flexibility to make up your own word, for example, you might "enpaper" it, or "paperize" it.

But like I say, it depends a lot on what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to consider a noun, try *[scrivening](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scrivening)*

> (obsolete) writing [*Collins*]

as in *I filled the paper with my scrivenings.*

You could also use the verb form *[scribe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scribe)*

> (chiefly LITERARY)  Write:
>   *he scribed a note that he passed to Dan* [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

But note that the verb is now more often used to describe marking with a sharp instrument rather than writing.

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally **Jot things down** on a napkin, envelope, scrap of paper; whatever's handy.

Answer (score -2):

Say:

> I need written statement.

This is my answer.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. Edited the answer a bit. **Do not pad.**

Comment: Look, someone down voted already.

Comment: “I need written statement” is not in use by native English speakers.  Say either “I need a written statement” or “I need written documentation” instead.  If you edit those into your answer I can upvote it